# Magento not showing products in category list page due to elastic search issue

Tags: magento2.4, category-products, elasticsearch

I am getting that exception when  view category in front end , I did re index also.

> [2023-11-09T05:26:45.393702+00:00] report.CRITICAL:
> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException:
> {"error":{"root_cause":
> [{"type":"no_shard_available_action_exception","reason":null,"index_uuid":"WJLPjai1SamDpLoyR_gerA","shard":"0","index":"intro-uat_product_1_v3"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
> shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"intro-uat_product_1_v3","node":null,"reason":{"type":"no_shard_available_action_exception","reason":null,"index_uuid":"WJLPjai1SamDpLoyR_gerA","shard":"0","index":"intro-uat_product_1_v3"}}]},"status":503}
> in
> /var/www/html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:726

Comment: Have you checked elasticsearch status on server side ?

Comment: I think it may be an elasticsearch version issue. Please try to update your elasticsearch version
See the following document for Magento 2 system requirements including Elasticsearch.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be your elastic search having an issue. please purge elastic search and reinstall maybe after that, it will work using the below command.

first, try to restart elastic search service using this command

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

After running this command issue still happened then purge and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /etc/elasticsearch
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch

sudo apt-get install elasticsearch={install latest version}
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
curl http://localhost:9200/
```